# Разобрать скрипт xPDO

Tags: php, pdo

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, почему у меня в $output попадают только последние значения с каждого цикла foreach? Что нужно поправить в коде?

```
<?php
$ids = $modx->resource->get('id');
if ($product = $modx->getObject('msProduct', $ids)) {
    $output .= $product->get('pagetitle');
    foreach ($product as $output) {
    $color = $product->get('color');
    foreach ($color as $cval) {
        $output .= $cval;
    }
    $putkart = $product->get('put_kartinka');
    foreach ($putkart as $putval) {
        $output .= $putval;
    }
    $nackart = $product->get('nacenka_kartinka');
    foreach ($nackart as $ncval) {
        $output .= $ncval;
    }
    }   

}
$output .= $modx->getChunk('Test', array('color' =>$cval, 'nacenka' => $ncval, 'putkart' => $putval) );
return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

В `$output` у вас конкатенируются (сцепляются) все значения. Конкатенируйте одно, например

```
foreach ($resources as $res) {

       $output .= '<p>'.implode(',', $res->get('nacenka_kartinka')).'</p>';

}
```

Comment: Что-то я хода не понял. В таком случае он мне выведет все значения их одного поля. Например 1500, 2000, 3500. А мне нужно чтобы он выводил по одному из значений за один проход цикла.

Comment: напишите пример того, что вы хотите получить

Comment: В поле color такие значения (к примеру) [«Венге»,«Дуб молочный»]
В поле put_kartinka ["/images/venge.jpg",«/images/dub.jpg»]
В поле nacenka_kartinka [«1500»,«2000»]

Мне нужно сделать вывод так, чтобы за первый обход вывелись все первые значения, потом все вторые и т.д. А у меня все просто в кучу выводит.
Таким образом получится блок с одними значениями,блок со вторыми и т.д.
<div>
  <div>Здесь из color</div>
  <div>Здесь из put_kartinka</div>
  <div>Здесь из nacenka_kartinka</div>
</div>

И тд.